# How do I use scoped_session properly with multiple databases?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am currently working on a flask app in which you can have multiple databases connected to it.

Each request to the app should be handled by a certain database depending on the url.

I am now trying to replace `flask-sqlalchemy` with `sqlalchemy` in order to use `scoped-session` to take care of my problem.

I have a `session_registry` in order to store the sessions:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

class SessionRegistry(object):
    _registry = {}

    def get_database_connection(self, name, **kwargs):
        return self._registry[name]

    def add_database_connection(self, url, name, **kwargs):
        if url not in self._registry:
            engine = create_engine(url)
            Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
            session = scoped_session(Session)
            self._registry[name] = session

        return True if self._registry[name] is not None else Fals
```

The problem that I have now is, that I don't know how to pass it to my routes in order to use that session. Here is an example class where I am trying to use it:

```py
class SomeJob():

    def get(self, lim=1000, order="asc"):

        if order == "desc":
            result = session.query(SomeModel).order_by(
                SomeModel.id.desc()).limit(lim).all()
        else:
            result = session.query(SomeModel).order_by(
                SomeModel.id.asc()).limit(lim).all()

        # deserialize to json
        schemaInstance = SomeSchema(many=True)
        json_res = schemaInstance.dump(result)

        # return json
        return json_res
```

My question now is, how do I pass that session to the object properly?

Comment: Just to check, you can't do what you want with [binds](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/binds/)?

Comment: There was an implementation which abused binds for switching them per request which has been copied from here: https://quanttype.net/posts/2016-03-15-flask-sqlalchemy-and-multitenancy.html
The problem is, that there is now a new requirement that the application should be able to handle multiple databases in a single request. All the Models are using the same db so as far as I know I can't use binds.

Comment: I solved my problem in the meantime. The solution for me was to make use of the ```@app.before_request``` from flask in which I assigned the session to the __g__ variable of flask. Then in my routes I just accessed it.